# How to autoscroll to a hidden div when using show hide funciton in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, intervals

I have a loop that displays tooltips in a sequence down a page.  One div will open for a few seconds, then close, then another div will open further down the page, and then close, etc.

How do I make the browser auto scroll to each div as it is opened without a click function?

My JavaScript for the loop looks like this:

```
    function fadeLoop() {

    var counter = 0,
        divs = $('.fader').css('visibility','visible').hide(),
        dur = 100;

    function showDiv() {
        divs.fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
            .filter(function(index) {
                return index == counter % divs.length;
            }) // figure out correct div to show
            .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
            .fadeIn(dur); // and show it
        counter++;
    }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
    showDiv(); // show first div    
    return setInterval(function() {
        showDiv(); // show next div
    }, 5 * 1000); // do this every 5 seconds    
};

$(function() {
    var interval;

    $(".start").click(function() {
        if (interval == undefined){
            interval = fadeLoop();
            $(this).val("Stop");
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(interval);
            $(this).val("Start");
            interval = undefined;
        }
    });
});
```

So when I click "Start" - the loop begins. I want the view to stay with the flow of opened divs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
.fadeIn(dur);
```

To:

```
.fadeIn(dur, function() {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: no dice... it didn't work; "Attempting to set focus to a hidden element causes an error in Internet Explorer. Take care to only use .focus() on elements that are visible. "

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/Arwid/jQuery.scrollIntoView, used it some times already and it did the trick pretty well. There's another similar plugin but this is more complete and stable (personal opinion).
You go simply with a:

```
$("#some_element").scrollIntoView();
```

More options are available on the Github page.
Anyway.. sounds like you are doing something like a "guided tour" in the dom. 
If that's the case, another great pick is: http://bootstraptour.com/ although its based on Bootstrap code (pretty small footprint anyway).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried to build a demo about what i understood you are looking for. If it's similar to what you want to achieve, i can articulate a better answer. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/CE6Ur/5/